# How to reference a Pandas Column that has a dot in the name and use it with first_valid_index()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, nan

I need to find the first valid index of the column 'A.b' that has a dot in its name in the following data frame :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'A.b': [np.nan, 2, np.nan, 4],
    'B': [5, 6, 7, np.nan],
    'C. e': ['us', 'uae', np.nan, 'baz'],
    'D': [np.nan, 'iq', 'bgd', 'erb']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I tried :

`df.A.b.first_valid_index()`

but got an error : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'A'

Comment: `df['A.b'].first_valid_index()`?

Answer (score 2):

In python strings are immutable also here `A.b` is considered as string and to access you need to use `df["A.b"]` not `df.A.b` , this is invalid.

Solution =>

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'A.b': [np.nan, 2, np.nan, 4],
    'B': [5, 6, 7, np.nan],
    'C. e': ['us', 'uae', np.nan, 'baz'],
    'D': [np.nan, 'iq', 'bgd', 'erb']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df["A.b"]) # use any method on the col fetched as series

# example 
df["A.b"].first_valid_index() # returns 1 as it is not NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always reference a dataframe column by index. Since your column is named by a string, use that:

```
df["A.b"].first_valid_index()
```

Dataframes have a convenience mechanism when reading an attribute. If the attribute doesn't already exist on the df, Pandas will first try to use it as a column name before raising an `AttributeError`. But that only works if (1) it's not the name of an existing method or attribute and (2) the column name is a string that follows Python attribute name syntax. Attribute names can't have "." so that doesn't work for you.

Since fetching columns by attribute access is somewhat fragile, it would be reasonable to not use that mechanism. In your case, if you have some conforming column names and some not, the code can end up looking a bit scattered if you mix access techniques.